# :focus ::after selector issue

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with ::after selector, heres my code:

HTML:

```
...

<div class="post">
    <form>
         <textarea placeholder="Message Here..." maxlength="255"></textarea>
    </form>
</div>

...
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper .left_section .profile_small .post form textarea:focus::after {
    content:"<input type='submit' value='Post' />"; 
}
```

So when the text area is selected (in focus) I'd like the submit button to appear.
Does anyone know of the solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/css-after-pseudo-element-on-input-field
Unfortunately, I think the `:before` and `:after` pseudoelements don't work on input or textareas

Comment: @Haroldchen - absolutely correct, it will need to be wrapped in say, a `div`

Comment: Plus, you can't use pseudo-elements to generate entirely new HTML elements. Because they are *pseudo-*elements. Your needs would be best served by a script.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS general sibling selector to do what you want — but you will have to place the submit button into your HTML first: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/qRtX6/

```
<div class="post">
    <form>
        <textarea placeholder="Message Here..." maxlength="255"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Post" />
    </form>
</div>
```

For your CSS:

```
input[type='submit'] {
    display: none;
}
textarea:focus ~ input[type='submit'] {
    display: block;
}
```

Caveat: The submit button has to be placed *after* the textarea element, as the general *successive* sibling selector only works downstream (i.e. it will not look for siblings preceding the textarea, thus the name *successive*).

Comment: Wow, didn't realize stuff like this could be done through CSS, nice example!

Answer (score 0):

here its another help with some jquery:

```
<html>
<head>  
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function onFocus(){

        }

        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myTextArea").on("focus" , function(){
            var btn = document.createElement("button")
            $(btn).append("submit");
            $(btn).attr("id" , "mySubmit");
            $("#container").append(btn);
        })

        $("#myTextArea").on("blur" , function(){
            $("#mySubmit").remove();
        })
        })          
    </script>
<head>
<body>
    <span id="container">
        <textarea id="myTextArea">
        </textarea>
    </span> 
</body>
```

Hope it helps you, cheers!

Comment: Good code, although its way too complex for what needs to be (after looking into it). Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use html in content tag in CSS for what I know

From [DevDocs css content](http://devdocs.io/css/content) page: `Formal syntax: normal | none | [ <string> | <uri> | <counter> | attr() | open-quote | close-quote | no-open-quote | no-close-quote ]+`

Answer (score 0):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( ".create_post" ).focus(function() {
      $( ".create_post" ).after("<input class='submit_post' type='submit' value='Post' />");
      $( ".profile" ).css("margin-bottom","71px");
    });
    $( ".create_post" ).focusout(function() {
      $( ".submit_post" ).remove();
      $( ".profile" ).css("margin-bottom","");
    });
});
```

Works.